# How To: 1 Bone Moves Entire Arm, While IK Bones Can Bend Arm

Tags: animation, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

I am trying to make a very simple character who has two IK bones in his arm (Besides Target and Pole) to move and bend it. At the moment I am to move his arm, bending it "realistically".  However, I am also wanting to be able to move the entire arm without it bending, like a Minecraft character.  How do I do this?  It wold be preferable if I could do this without creating a new armature.  Is that possible?  I am also trying to keep my armature(s) simple, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my own answer.
If I keep my target far enough away from the arm bones, the arm will stay stiff.  I could animate it that way, by moving it, say, 1.5 m away from the arm on its local Z axis.  When I want to bend it, I can move it in closer on the local Z axis.
Whether this is an efficient method, I don't know, but I think it will work for me.
I am going to leave this question open for other suggestions at this time.